# How laravel `Auth:user()` or `Auth:id()` works

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-authorization

How laravel `Auth:user()` or `Auth:id()` works

Is it resides in session or database.

I searched but not get good article.

Please help to understand.  I know I will get many down-votes ;)

Comment: It lives in a Session

Comment: @Farkie : please can you give me source from where you got this info. I want to know more about this.

Comment: Laravel use session for authentication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you read this? Its a good guide to start with

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question of "how".  When I look at that class (vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Auth.php) it has two methods, neither of which are user(), and extends an abstract class (Facade) that likewise doesn't have a user() method.  And I don't see how the __callStatic method would do anything outside of those two classes either.  HOW exactly does Auth::user() work?

Answer (score 8):

Here's my attempt at figuring out what actually happens on an `Auth::user()` call:

```
Auth::user()

Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth
extends Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade

Facade::__callStatic('user')

static::getFacadeRoot()

resolveFacadeInstance(static::getFacadeAccessor == 'auth' (from Auth class))

return static::$app[$name];
static::$app is instance of Illuminate\Foundation\Application
extends Illuminate\Container\Container
```

which implements `ArrayAccess` (which is why `$obj[]` syntax works)

```
Container::offsetGet(auth)

Application::make(auth) 

Container::getAlias(auth) return 'auth'

Container::make(auth)

Container::resolve(auth)
```

yadda, yadda, yadda
See in `Application::registerCoreContainerAliases`

```
'auth' = Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager

AuthManager::user() = AuthManager::__call = $this->guard()->user()

AuthManager::guard(web)

AuthManager::resolve(web) (see config/auth.php)

AuthManager::createSessionDriver() returns new Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard

SessionGuard::user() // <---- this is what actually get's called, based on default config
```

Comment: I had this question too and this answer really helped. I needed to figure out whether `Auth::user()` and `Auth::id()` retrieved the details from the database or session. From reading the source of `SessionGuard::user()` and `SessionGuard::id()` it appears:

1. The value is reused from memory if this call has been made previously within the current request.
2. The value is called from the proper provider (Which is often the db) if it is not currently in memory.
3. For `Auth::id` the value is exclusively pulled from the Session.

Note that if you use the DB for sessions this is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

laravel uses session for authentication.if you are beginer in laravel then must read following link:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication

i think its help you

Answer (score 1):

You can find this method in Auth\SessionGuard class :

> Authenticatable|null user()
>
> Get the currently authenticated user.
>
> Return Value Authenticatable|null

Check it out: https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Auth/SessionGuard.html#method_user